# How to implement admob native ads in Doubleclick For Publishers?

Tags: android, admob, google-dfp, double-click-advertising, native-ads

I am new to Doubleclick platform, I want to implement Admob Native Ad through DFP to my android application.. Please help.. Provide step wise guide if possible. Thanks in advance..!

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start

Comment: hello @DanielStorm but can you help me out integrating it in DPF? How can I connect it to DFP?

Comment: @ShubhamHirve do you currently have a DFP account? If you do, check the sample native ads in Google's GitHub repo: https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/tree/master/java/admob. For the DFP side, you can check this guidelines from the DFP Help Center: https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/6366905?hl=en